# In C++ How to detect EOF in arm architecture

Tags: c++, arm, beagleboneblack

```
f=fopen("/dev/ttyUSB0","r")
char c;
c=getc(f);
while(c!=EOF) {
    c=getc(f);
}
```

In the code above loop never breaks on beaglebone ubuntu which is arm architecture when I unplug device. The above code worked on my i386 ubuntu desktop.

--EDIT--

Its very weird! Mike's `int c`; didn't work. Watch on `c` gives `c=255` but even when I changed `c!=EOF` to `c!=255` loop don't break!! I'm very frustrated after trying for an hour!!!

--EDIT--

I tried `fstream fin("/dev/ttyUSB0", fstream::in);`. when I unplug the input serial device `fin>>c` never returns and CPU usage is 100%!! I expect its a bug!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the type of `c` from `char` to `int`. `EOF` is outside the range of `char`.

To clarify, by "change the type", I mean change the declaration to

```
int c;
```

not cast the value back to `int` after truncating it to `char`.

Comment: s i did it, I tried both `(int)c!=EOF` and `c!=(int)EOF`. it never worked.

Comment: @neckTwi That's not the problem. use `int c; c=getc(f)`

Comment: @neckTwi: No, they won't work. You've already converted the result of `getc` to `char` when you assigned it to `c`, and the converted value will never be `EOF` since that can't be represented by a `char`. As I said, change the type of `c` to `int` so that it can represent `EOF`.

Comment: you must declare c as int, not casting it to int. Because getc's result includes all 256 possible values of char (assuming char is 8 bit) and EOF, so char is not enough to store all that case and. As  result you must use a wider type to check

Comment: I think now i understood type casting. but I don understand y the code worked on my i386 ubuntu desktop.

Comment: @neckTwi: It's possible that the conversion to `char` and back might preserve the value of `EOF` on some platforms, but change it on others. The exact value of `EOF` isn't specified and can change from implementation to implementation.

Comment: @neckTwi: Then maybe you're not getting `EOF` from the device at all. I'm afraid I can't help with that.

Comment: I'm unplugging the device to get `EOF`, so definitely getc returns `EOF`

Comment: I kept watch on `c` and it shows `c=255`. But Even `c!=255` don exit the loop! Its very very weird!

Comment: @neckTwi: If you're getting 255, then either you haven't changed it to `int`, or something is wrong somewhere else. `EOF` should be a negative value.

Comment: I cleaned all the files and I compiled again and it never break the loop. I'm giving up. Thanq!

Answer (score 0):

In C++ it is easier to use cin.

```
int main()
{
    char ch;

    while (true)
    {
        cin >> ch;
        if (!cin.good())
            break;

        // Do something with you character
    }
}
```

This will stop when con >> ch fails.

Comment: Or just `while (cin >> c) { /* do something */ }`

Comment: `fstream fin("/dev/ttyUSB0", fstream::in);`. when I unplug the device `fin>>c` never returns and CPU usage is 100%

Comment: You can just open an ifstream fin like you said and then replace it cin in my code with fin, does that not work?

Comment: no it didn't work. Upon debugging I found that `fin>>ch` never returned when device unplugged and cpu usage became 100%. so it might have looping infinitely inside `fin`.